# Rails Sub-resources Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, nested-resources

I'm having trouble using sub-resources in my Rails application.
My goal is to have routes (example application) such as

/people/1/jokes/new
/people/1/jokes

The form_for line in my jokes form is turning up the routing error

```
undefined method `jokes_path'
```

See all source files here: https://gist.github.com/maclover7/14c9d6eaa0c6731a3ecf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that after you put the `jokes` resource under `people` as a sub-resource, the route helpers for the `jokes` change to have `user` prefix as follows:

```
  user_jokes_path # => /people/1/jokes
  new_user_jokes_path # => /people/1/jokes/new
  edit_user_jokes_path # => /poople/1/jokes/:id/edit
```

Also note that you need to pass `user.id` to the path as part of the parameters, so if you are using `user_jokes_path` you need to call it by passing the `user` object, so if your are storing the user record in `@user` variable:

```
<%= link_to 'jokes', user_jokes_path(@user)%>
```

The best approach is to use `rake routes` command to see the routes table for your application and find out what it generated